# (Probably Webpack Error) in Production Environment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at c (harmony module decorator:7

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I'm facing an issue with my front-end application that is bundled using Webpack and written in React. The problem is, I keep getting the following error in my production environment

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raqwu.png)
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at c (harmony module decorator:7:20)`

The error seems to occur randomly throughout the application when I try to access a page and a blank screen is returned. Interestingly, this issue does not occur in my local development environment - only in my production environment.

For infrastructure, we're publishing as a static web app on Azure Blob Storage and exposing it through Azure Front Door (we were deactivated cache on both using cache-control header)

I´m using the 16.13.1 version of React and 5.51.1 of webpack and 14.18.1 of node.

Here is my Webpack configuration:

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const singleSpaDefaults = require("webpack-config-single-spa-ts");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const orgName = "Aberto";
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName,
    projectName: "root-config",
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
    disableHtmlGeneration: true,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    externals: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    optimization: {
      sideEffects: false
    },
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')
      },
      modules: [__dirname, "node_modules"],
      alias: {
        process: "process/browser",
        environment: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'environments', process.env.CLIENT_ENV),
        externalConfig: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'environments', 'externalConfig'),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.csv$/,
          loader: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        inject: false,
        template: "public/index.ejs",
        templateParameters: {
          isLocal: webpackConfigEnv && webpackConfigEnv.isLocal,
          orgName,
        },
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        process: 'process/browser',
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: 'public' }
        ]
      }),
    ],
  });
};
```

We´re using additional module (Single-SPA) to implement a MFE solution, but the error occurs on pages thats directed configured on root app.

We have tried disabling the lazy-loading to see if it could be related to the issue but unfortunately, the problem persists even with lazy-loading turned off.

I have tried to investigate this issue, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem might be. I suspect that it might have something to do with the chunks and how they are being loaded, but I'm not sure how to confirm this.

Any help or suggestions on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated!